# multiple child views inside expandablelistview of android application

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I have two imageviews in my group header of expandable listview.Based on the imageview clicked, I want to open my child view.How would I get the imageview clicked in the getChildView method of my expandableListviewAdapter

Answer (score 1):

Use `onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition)` to check which group(imageview) is expanded.

Comment: If I understood correctly,group position would return the row on which the user clicks, but I have two imageviews within that group header, how would i know which imageview got clicked inside getChildView method?

Comment: Then set onClicklistener for imageviews. Also maintain two list. If user click the particular imageview then change the list depends on the imageview, after that call notifyDataSetChanged

Comment: so i cant get which imageview got clicked inside the getCildView method of my adapter?

Comment: You can use a variable to set which imageview clicked. Depends on the variable you can change the childview. Then you call notifydatasetChanged